# uvnc - connecting to a nat without port forwarding

Tags: lan, vnc, vncserver

How can I connect to a vnc server from outside of that LAN without setting up port forwarding,m assuming there are no ports blocked. I have the network IP and the PC's ip on that network.

I've noticed that SiteKiosk is able to connect to a machine (using uvnc) without any changes to the router or network configuration, so it is possible somehow. I've noticed it is using UDP ports 55660 and 50606. And I don' think it is using NSC.exe

Comment: Are you sure SiteKiosk isn't setting up a VPN or something just for the VNC traffic?

Comment: Perhaps SiteKiosk is using UPnP. UPnP basically setups port forwarding automatically on the NAT router when the application starts.

Comment: I'm not sure how they handle it... this is some of the info they provide "`On the SiteKiosk Client machine:
The Teredo version requires at least UDP 3544 (out), which will enable you to connect to clients within the same network, for machines outside the same network all outbound UDP traffic must be allowed.

The repeater version requires TCP 5500 (out), UDP 55901 (out) and UDP 55900 (in). `"

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention a firewall, but I'm assuming there is one in this problem.

Default configuration for your average firewall is to allow all OUTBOUND traffic. Most GoToMyPC, TeamViewer, etc. clients work by establishing the connection outbound from the client, and the firewall allows the return traffic. I'm not seeing the specifics on SiteKiosk.

If you are originating the connection from the outside of the firewall using standard RDP/VNC/etc. tools, you will need to open ports on the firewall.

Comment: sitekiosk, like the others you mentioned relies on outbound traffic

Comment: Okay, then perhaps clarify your question? VNC Server does not work this way. You'd need to pick another software package, or open the ports. http://www.realvnc.com/products/vnc/documentation/5.0/guides/user/ae1017368.html#Rae54344

Comment: sitekiosk is using uvnc though, so it's possible using http://www.uvnc.com/

Comment: Given that the UVNC documentation demands port forwarding [link](http://www.uvnc.com/docs/uvnc-server.html) they must be triggering it using their own application. Alternatively, I also saw the word "repeater" on the SiteKiosk site, so maybe that's how they're doing it. [link](http://www.uvnc.com/docs/uvnc-repeater.html)